# Form Id can't recognise addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How do I solve the error `cannot read property of 'addEventListener' of null` ? when I add this code,`document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", SaveBookmark)` in my JS file

```
 <form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="siteName" size="75%" placeholder="Twitter"><tr>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website URL" size="75%" id="siteName"><br>
      <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: can you add a code snippet please? it's fair easy to answer if you do it.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the `javascript` before the DOM is ready (loaded)? If so then you can place that `script` into a DOM ready/`onload` function or place the `script` below the element / bottom of the page so it will execute after the element has loaded/rendered.

Comment: Where is your JS code located? Are you attempting to use HTML elements before DOM is fully rendered?

Comment: As mentioned NewToJS, seems you're calling before Dom is loaded. Please full Javascript code here.

Answer (score 1):

First please notice that you're calling DOM is loaded or duplicated `formID`.
This code is working fine. please change `<button type="button">` to be `<button type="submit" .../>`

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="siteName" size="75%" placeholder="Twitter"><tr>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website URL" size="75%" id="siteName"><br>
      <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>

    document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", SaveBookmark);

    function SaveBookmark() {
        alert('success');
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert but to avoid that error your JS should look like this

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

if (myForm) {
  myForm.addEventListener("submit", SaveBookmark)
}
```

This ensures that your form element exists before you add the event listener

Answer (score 0):

Should work easily:

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
  alert("yes!")
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="siteName" size="75%" placeholder="Twitter"><tr>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website URL" size="75%" id="siteName"><br>
      <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not work because you have a

```
<button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

instead of:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

and you're trying to reach submit event.
Anyway, i recommend you not to add event listeners due to resource wasting. Use it when it's the only option.

I let you another way to reach the same with default click eventlistener:

```html
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="siteName" size="75%" placeholder="Twitter"><tr>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website URL" size="75%" id="siteName"><br>
      <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="saveBookmark()">Submit</button>
 </form>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
function saveBookmark(){
 alert ("Bookmark saved");
}

 </script>
```

You'll click on submit button anyway so, use onclick event instead of creating an eventlistener. It works simplest and waste much less resources...

And remember to add action attribute to the form, trying to re-program defined behaviour will only make your software heavy and heavy on codelines and timeloads. Thats why know the language its important.

Hope it help!

Comment: This method will work but it doesn't really explain why `addEventListener` isn't functioning as intended as the OP is asking.

Comment: because this was explained by Alexander Biship a pair of coments before, would you prefere to duplicate info?
I'm adding an alternative and explaining that adding an eventlistener waste more resources than using a default one. What does your comment add to this question?

Comment: If you choose to submit a solution then I would recommend you include the relevant information to answer why the current attempt isn't working. Comments from other users can be removed at any given time so including all relevant information in your solution then provides a solid/detailed answer and more likely to be marked. So my comment add advice to help you provide a more suitable answer since someone else has already down voted you for this one.

Comment: K' it's done, hope it likes you and thanks for the advice